# Datagridview crashing on selection of checkbox

Tags: c#

**Situation**

I am working on a program where from a datagrid, I select X amount of rows and forward them for processing. So I will select 5 student out of my list and on a button click event, send their IDs to another method.

So far, I have loaded my data into my grid, I've done this two ways, by using the data source of the table, and by using table adapters. Like the following.

```
 private void printStudentCard_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //   metroGrid2.Rows.Add(true);


        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        string sql = "SELECT listOfFields FROM Students";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        connection.Open();
        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Students");
        connection.Close();
        metroGrid2.DataSource = ds;
        metroGrid2.DataMember = "Students";


    }
```

Now for both tables I have entered the edit columns option and selected to add a checkbox button.

**Problem**

The problem is, when I select a checkbox to "check it" the program immediately crashes with the following

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
```

and points to

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1()); //Error on here
}
```

in the program.cs file. (thought I think that has nothing to do with it);

```
<ExceptionString>System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: rowIndex
```

I am aware that out of range exceptions is most likely because of an invalid length but I am really not sure where that might be occurring.

Any help offered would be appreciated, adding the rest of my code for context

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("Students");
    private void printMultiCard_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        string sql = "SELECT listOfFields FROM Students";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        connection.Open();
        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Students");
        connection.Close();
        metroGrid2.DataSource = ds;
        metroGrid2.DataMember = "Students";


    }

    private void metroGrid1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void metroGrid2_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void metroGrid2_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("stest");
    }
```

Stack Trace

```
<StackTrace>   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.GetValue(Int32 rowIndex)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.SetValue(Int32 rowIndex, Object value)
   at DevComponents.DotNetBar.Controls.DataGridViewCheckBoxXCell.OnMouseUp(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.OnMouseUpInternal(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellMouseUp(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message&amp;amp; m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG&amp;amp; msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at MPID_App.Program.Main() in H:\Documents\Projects\Application\MApp\MApp\Program.cs:line 20
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: rowIndex
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.GetValue(Int32 rowIndex)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.SetValue(Int32 rowIndex, Object value)
   at DevComponents.DotNetBar.Controls.DataGridViewCheckBoxXCell.OnMouseUp(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.OnMouseUpInternal(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellMouseUp(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message&amp;amp; m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
```

Comment: What type of application is this? Windows Forms, WPF, or a Windows Universal app?

Comment: @TiesonT. Sorry forms, windows forms

Comment: Okay. Are you using a plain old [DataGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx), or is this some sort of third-party control?

Comment: @TiesonT. Im using metro datagrid but it does inherit from the datagrid and works the same, except it's styled and minor

Comment: Please clarify "and points to", that is a few lines of code or are you not able to examine/show the complete stack trace from the exception for some reason?

Comment: @blins I've added it

Comment: After the DGV/MGV is loaded does it actually have rows? (If in doubt use the debugger, but you should be able to see it..) - Is `listOfFields` a single string field in the db?

Comment: @TaW Yes, there are rows from my database. no `listOfFields` isnt, I had a long list of columns so i just replacced it with that.

Comment: OK. So one of the fields was a bool that created a chaeckbox column? Is the code in the click event or any other that might be invoked by the click? Can you use the debugger to stop there and find out what rowIndex is?

Comment: @TaW No, none of the rows were a bool, I added the checkbox in the datagrid "Add column" menu

Comment: Have you seen this: [How to: Bind Objects to Windows Forms DataGridView Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-objects-to-windows-forms-datagridview-controls)?

Comment: Seeing as you added the checkbox column, is there an event handler listening to that and processing it once the user checks the checkbox?

Answer (score 3):

The stack trace shows the following line shortly before the crash occurs:

> DevComponents.DotNetBar.Controls.DataGridViewCheckBoxXCell.OnMouseUp

So I would suggest reverting to an out-of-the-box DataGridView, to isolate whether the problem is being caused by that component.

The question doesn't contain an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but the sample that I have created putting a DataSet with a table of Students into an out-of-the-box DataGridView's DataSource, where one of the columns in the `DataTable` is a checkbox column, and I have manually added a checkbox column (like you're doing) doesn't have this problem.

Some unrelated tips: `SqlConnection` and `SqlDataAdapter` are both `IDisposable` so should be in `using` blocks. Once you've done that, you won't need the `connection.Close();`, since exiting the `using` block will call `Dispose()`, which will do that for you.